# Create a dynamic list using a table range in vba

Tags: excel, vba, list

My goal is to created a dynamic list using the column of my table. Excel says theres a type mistmatch on the line where i add the validation list. A,B,C are integers. i want to create a xlvalidatelist using a range.

```
With Cells(B, A).Validation
     .Delete
     .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
      Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(C + 1).Range, ",")
End With
```

Comment: There is no question here. Please write a few lines explaining what you want, what you did, what didn't work, ...

Comment: What are `B`, `A`, and `C`?

Comment: Hopefuly, its more clear now.

Comment: It isn't much clearer. Why not provide a [mcve]?

Comment: From a debugging point of view, declare a string variable, say `formula`, and split the problem line into 3 lines: `formula = Join(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(C + 1).Range, ",")` followed by `Debug.Print formula` and then finally `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:= formula`. That should help focus your debugging efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following replacement for your `.Add` line:

```
 .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
  Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(c + 1).Range.Address
```

This will create a validation list pointing at column C+1 of the table. However, it will include the fieldname/header.

To exclude the fieldname/header, use `DataBodyRange` property instead of `Range`:

```
 .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
  Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(c + 1).DataBodyRange.Address
```

Comment: @Pierre If the answer solved your problem, consider marking it as "accepted" (via the check mark next to the answer).